# How can I make the computer make better guesses in this program?

Tags: python

```
print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\nTry to guess is in as few attempt as possible.")

import random

number = random.randrange (1, 100) #This creates a random # from 1 to 100
guess = 0 #This helps initiate the while loop

while guess != number: #While the guess does not equal the random number
    guess = int(input("\nTake a guess: "))
    if guess <number:
        print("Player guess higher...")
    elif guess >number:
        print("Player guess lower...")
    else:
        guess == number
        print(f"\nGame over! The number was {number} The Player Wins!")

        break

    computer_guess = random.randrange (1, 100)#This makes the computer make a new guess every turn...

    if computer_guess <number:
        print(f"\nThe computer guesses {computer_guess}")
        print("Computer guess higher...")
    elif computer_guess >number:
        print(f"\nThe computer guesses {computer_guess}")
        print("Computer guess lower...")
    else:
        computer_guess == number
        print(f"\nGame over! The number was {number} The Computer Wins!")

        break
    


input("\nPress Enter to Exit")
```

#What must I add to make this computer make better guesses - so far it does not make really good guesses with the current code
#Any suggestions will be helpful!
#I do not know what else to add so here is an extra line with some extra text

Comment: decrease the range of the randomness for the "computer" like you do for the user. user uses the information to guess higher/lower than previous guess, the computer is always guessing with a probability of 1/100

Answer (score 0):

Since the user can view what the computer is guessing, you could add a few additional variables to keep track of the user's high and low guesses as well as what the outcome of the computer's guesses were.  Following is an enhancement to your code to provide a little more intelligence to the computer's guesses by reducing the range of guesses.

```
print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\nTry to guess is in as few attempt as possible.")

import random

number = random.randrange (1, 100) #This creates a random # from 1 to 100
guess = 0 #This helps initiate the while loop

comp  = 1  # This will hold the computer's last guess
user  = 1  # This will hold the user's last guess
floor = 1  # This will be adjusted to reduce the lowest guess for the computer
top   = 99 # This will be adjusted to reduce the highest guess for the computer

while guess != number: #While the guess does not equal the random number
    guess = int(input("\nTake a guess: "))
    user  = guess  # Store the user's latest guess
    if guess <number:
        print("Player guess higher...")
        if (comp < user):
            comp = top
    elif guess >number:
        print("Player guess lower...")
        if (comp > user):
            comp = floor
    else:
        guess == number
        print(f"\nGame over! The number was {number} The Player Wins!")
    
        break

    if (comp <= user):
        computer_guess = random.randrange (comp, user)
    else:
        computer_guess = random.randrange (user, comp)
    
    comp = computer_guess   # Store the computer's latest guess

    if computer_guess <number:
        print(f"\nThe computer guesses {computer_guess}")
        print("Computer guess higher...")
        floor = comp  # Adjust the low range 
    elif computer_guess >number:
        print(f"\nThe computer guesses {computer_guess}")
        print("Computer guess lower...")
        top = comp    # Adjust the high end range
    else:
        computer_guess == number
        print(f"\nGame over! The number was {number} The Computer Wins!")
    
    break
```

There are probably a few other tests that could be added to bring the guessing range down for the computer, but this provides a little better advantage for the computer to occasionally win.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

the only way that keep your program fair for user and computer is, when user see the result of guess after pre round, in the next round select number from new range of previuse round (less or greater than pre guess) so for the computer also you shoud write code like below

```
print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\nTry to guess is in as 
few attempt as possible.")

import random
down=1
up=100
number = random.randrange (1, 100) #This creates a random # from 1 to 100
guess = 0 #This helps initiate the while loop

while guess != number: #While the guess does not equal the random number
    guess = int(input("\nTake a guess: "))
    if guess <number:
        print("Player guess higher...")
    elif guess >number:
        print("Player guess lower...")
    else:
        guess == number
        print(f"\nGame over! The number was {number} The Player Wins!")

        break

    computer_guess = random.randrange (down, up)#This makes the computer 
    make a new guess every turn...

    if computer_guess <number:
        print(f"\nThe computer guesses {computer_guess}")
        print("Computer guess higher...")
        down=computer_guess
    elif computer_guess >number:
        print(f"\nThe computer guesses {computer_guess}")
        print("Computer guess lower...")
        up=computer_guess
        
    else:
        computer_guess == number
        print(f"\nGame over! The number was {number} The Computer Wins!")

        break
    


input("\nPress Enter to Exit")
```

and also its better to create random number one time and then start game not in every round

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but this suggestion does not work.